# Cash Register Challenge

Tags: java, programming-challenge, change-making-problem

**Challenge**:

> Design a cash register program

**Specifications**:

> Your register currently has the following bills/coins within it:

'PENNY': .01,

'NICKEL': .05,

'DIME': .10,

'QUARTER': .25,

'HALF DOLLAR': .50,

'ONE': 1.00,

'TWO': 2.00,

'FIVE': 5.00,

'TEN': 10.00,

'TWENTY': 20.00,

'FIFTY': 50.00,

'ONE HUNDRED': 100.00

Your program should accept as its first argument a path to a filename.
  The input file contains several lines. Each line is one test case.
  Each line contains two numbers which are separated by a semicolon.
  The first is the Purchase price (PP) and the second is the cash(CH).

For each set of input produce a single line of output,
  which is the cashBack to be returned to the customer.
  In case the CH < PP, print out ERROR. If CH == PP, print out ZERO.
  For all other cases print the amount that needs to be returned,
  in terms of the currency values provided.
  The output should be sorted in highest-to-lowest order

**Solution**:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CashRegister {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File(args[0]);
        Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(file);

        while (fileInput.hasNextLine()) {
            printCashChange(fileInput.nextLine());
        }
    }

    private static void printCashChange(String line) {
        float pp = Float.parseFloat(line.split(";")[0]);
        float ch = Float.parseFloat(line.split(";")[1]);

        System.out.println(getCashChange(pp, ch));
    }

    private static String getCashChange(float price, float cash) {
        if (cash < price) { return "ERROR"; }
        if (cash == price) { return "ZERO"; }
        float cashBack = cash - price;


        StringBuilder change = new StringBuilder();

        while (cashBack > 0.01f) {
            if (cashBack >= 100.0f) {
                change.append("ONE HUNDRED");
                cashBack -= 100.0f;
            } else if (cashBack >= 50.0f) {
                change.append("FIFTY");
                cashBack -= 50.0f;
            } else if (cashBack >= 20.0f) {
                change.append("TWENTY");
                cashBack -= 20.0f;
            } else if (cashBack >= 10.0f) {
                change.append("TEN");
                cashBack -= 10.0f;
            } else if (cashBack >= 5.0f) {
                change.append("FIVE");
                cashBack -= 5.0f;
            } else if (cashBack >= 2.0f) {
                change.append("TWO");
                cashBack -= 2.0f;
            } else if (cashBack >= 1.0f) {
                change.append("ONE");
                cashBack -= 1.0f;
            } else if (cashBack >= 0.5f) {
                change.append("HALF DOLLAR");
                cashBack -= 0.5f;
            } else if (cashBack >= 0.25f) {
                change.append("QUARTER");
                cashBack -= 0.25f;
            } else if (cashBack >= 0.1f) {
                change.append("DIME");
                cashBack -= 0.1f;
            } else if (cashBack >= 0.05f) {
                change.append("NICKEL");
                cashBack -= 0.05f;
            } else {
                change.append("PENNY");
                cashBack -= 0.01f;
            }
            change.append(",");
        }
        change.setLength(change.length() - 1);

        return change.toString();
    }
}
```

Every now and then one creates a solution that works but really comes off as sub-optimal, this is one of those times for this CRer. It really seems verbose, I'd appreciate any tips on improving performance and general structure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For convenience, even though the challenge doesn't specify it, I suggest optionally taking input from `System.in`.  It's more reasonable behaviour than crashing with an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

```
Scanner input = (args.length > 0) ? new Scanner(new File(args[0]))
                                  : new Scanner(System.in);
```

In `printCashChange()`, avoid two calls to `split()`.

```
String[] fields = line.split(";", 2);
float pp = Float.parseFloat(fields[0]);
float ch = Float.parseFloat(fields[1]);
```

The loop in `getCashChange()` should be data-driven, like this:

```
for (Denomination d : Denomination.values()) {
    while (cashBack >= d.getValue()) {
        cashBack -= d.getValue();
        change.append(d).append(',');
    }
}
```

Here's an enum to support that:

```
public enum Denomination {
    ONE_HUNDRED(100.00f),
          FIFTY( 50.00f),
         TWENTY( 20.00f),
            TEN( 10.00f),
           FIVE(  5.00f),
            TWO(  2.00f),
            ONE(  1.00f),
    HALF_DOLLAR(  0.50f),
        QUARTER(  0.25f),
           DIME(  0.10f),
         NICKEL(  0.05f),
          PENNY(  0.01f);

    private final float value;
    private final String description;

    Denomination(float value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.description = this.name().replace("_", " ");
    }

    public float getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.description;
    }
}
```

The performance of your program will be fine.  You aren't doing anything particularly inefficient, and the bottleneck will be I/O rather than processing.

Comment: This part is clever: `for (Denomination d : Denomination.values()) { while (cashBack >= d.getValue()) { ... }`. One more thing, how do you ensure that always the bigger value will get substracted first?

Comment: @yadav_vi [Enumerations have a static `values` method that returns an array containing all of the values of the enum in the order they are declared.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

Comment: I would really like to know how you approach the code. For e.g. I would never have come up with something like this - `Denomination(float value) { ... this.description = this.name().replace("_", " "); ...}` and then using it as `public String toString() { return this.description; }` and finally as `change.append(d).append(',');`. If you have a `git` repo for the code, please post it here too.