# Let's Break Down the Party

Tags: java, rags-to-riches

This is a [rags-to-riches](/questions/tagged/rags-to-riches) question, the original is here: [Coin dispenser program](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/82689/coin-dispenser-program)

There are three parts to this, a `Denomination` `enum`, a `Calculator` utility class and the unit test for it, using TestNG.

Please feel free to comment on any parts of the code, including comments.

**`Denomination` `enum`**

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Objects;

public enum Denomination {
    A_MILLION(1_000_000, "$1 million"),
    FIFTY_DOLLARS(50, "$50"),
    TWENTY_DOLLARS(20, "$20"),
    TEN_DOLLARS(10, "$10"),
    FIVE_DOLLARS(5, "$5"),
    DOLLAR_NINETY_NINE(1.99, "$1.99"),
    A_DOLLAR(1, "$1"),
    QUARTER(0.25, "25¢"),
    DIME(0.1, "10¢"),
    NICKEL(0.05, "5¢"),
    A_CENT(0.01, "1¢");

    private final BigDecimal value;
    private String description;

    private Denomination(double value, final String description) {
        this.value = BigDecimal.valueOf(value);
        this.description = Objects.requireNonNull(description);
    }

    /**
     * @param input the value to compare against
     * @return <code>true</code> if <code>input</code> is not smaller than the current value
     */
    public boolean canBreakdown(double input) {
        return BigDecimal.valueOf(input).compareTo(value) >= 0;
    }

    /**
     * Breaks down the input against the current value.
     *
     * @param input the input to start
     * @return a two-element array, the first being the quotient (aka multiplier) and the second
     *         being the remainder
     */
    public double[] breakdown(double input) {
        final BigDecimal[] results = BigDecimal.valueOf(input).divideAndRemainder(value);
        return new double[] { results[0].doubleValue(), results[1].doubleValue() };
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return description;
    }

    /**
     * @param multiplier the value to represent
     * @return a representation of the multiplier and the current value
     */
    public String toString(int multiplier) {
        return String.format("%d x %s", Integer.valueOf(multiplier), toString());
    }

    /**
     * @param multiplier the value to multiply with
     * @return the product of the multiplier and the current value
     */
    public double multiply(int multiplier) {
        return value.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(multiplier)).doubleValue();
    }

}
```

**`Calculator` utility class**

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.EnumMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

/**
 * Utility class for manipulating with {@link Denomination} enums.
 */
public class Calculator {

    private Calculator() {
        // empty
    }

    /**
     * Break down the input into {@link Denomination} values.
     *
     * @param input the value to break down
     * @return an unmodifiable {@link Map} with the {@link Denomination} as keys and a positive
     *         integer, the multiplier, as values
     */
    public static Map<Denomination, Integer> getBreakdown(double input) {
        final Map<Denomination, Integer> result = new EnumMap<>(Denomination.class);
        double temp = input;
        for (final Denomination current : Denomination.values()) {
            if (current.canBreakdown(temp)) {
                final double[] parts = current.breakdown(temp);
                result.put(current, Integer.valueOf(Double.valueOf(parts[0]).intValue()));
                temp = parts[1];
            }
        }
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(result);
    }

    /**
     * @param map the {@link Map} to generate from
     * @return a human-reable output
     */
    public static String format(Map<Denomination, Integer> map) {
        return Objects.requireNonNull(map).entrySet().stream()
                .map(e -> e.getKey().toString(e.getValue().intValue()))
                .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
    }

    /**
     * @param map the {@link Map} to generate from
     * @return the sum of the product of the map's keys and values
     */
    public static double compute(Map<Denomination, Integer> map) {
        return Objects.requireNonNull(map).entrySet().stream()
                .mapToDouble(e -> e.getKey().multiply(e.getValue().intValue())).sum();
    }
}
```

**`CalculatorTest` unit test**

```
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.EnumMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;

import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class CalculatorTest {

    @DataProvider(name = "test-cases")
    public Iterator<Object[]> getTestCases() {
        final Collection<Object[]> cases = new ArrayList<>();
        addCase(cases, 0, CaseBuilder.createEmpty());
        addCase(cases, 0.01, CaseBuilder.create(Denomination.A_CENT, 1));
        addCase(cases, 1.28, CaseBuilder.create(Denomination.A_DOLLAR, 1)
                                            .with(Denomination.QUARTER, 1)
                                            .with(Denomination.A_CENT, 3));
        addCase(cases, 19.48, CaseBuilder.create(Denomination.TEN_DOLLARS, 1)
                                            .with(Denomination.FIVE_DOLLARS, 1)
                                            .with(Denomination.DOLLAR_NINETY_NINE, 2)
                                            .with(Denomination.QUARTER, 2));
        addCase(cases, 100.75, CaseBuilder.create(Denomination.FIFTY_DOLLARS, 2)
                                            .with(Denomination.QUARTER, 3));
        addCase(cases, 1_000_040.15, CaseBuilder.create(Denomination.A_MILLION, 1)
                                            .with(Denomination.TWENTY_DOLLARS, 2)
                                            .with(Denomination.DIME, 1)
                                            .with(Denomination.NICKEL, 1));
        return cases.iterator();
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "test-cases")
    public void test(final Double testValue, final CaseBuilder builder) {
        final Map<Denomination, Integer> expected = Objects.requireNonNull(builder).getExpected();
        assertThat(Calculator.getBreakdown(Objects.requireNonNull(testValue).doubleValue()),
                equalTo(expected));
        assertThat(Double.valueOf(Calculator.compute(expected)), equalTo(testValue));
    }

    private static void addCase(final Collection<Object[]> cases, double testValue,
            final CaseBuilder builder) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(cases).add(new Object[] { Double.valueOf(testValue), builder });
    }

    /**
     * Helper class to build the expected {@link Map} of denominations and multipliers.
     */
    private static final class CaseBuilder {
        private final Map<Denomination, Integer> map;

        private CaseBuilder(final Map<Denomination, Integer> map) {
            this.map = map;
        }

        static CaseBuilder create(final Denomination denomination, int multiplier) {
            return new CaseBuilder(new EnumMap<>(Denomination.class))
                    .with(denomination, multiplier);
        }

        static CaseBuilder createEmpty() {
            return new CaseBuilder(Collections.EMPTY_MAP);
        }

        /**
         * Let <em>v</em> be the sum of the current value and <code>multiplier</code>.<br>
         * If <em>v</em> is greater than zero, the value is updated as such, else the entry for
         * <code>denominator</code> is removed.<br>
         * As such, the generated {@link Map} will only have denominators with positive multipliers.
         *
         * @param denomination the denomination to add
         * @param multiplier the multiplier to add
         * @return this {@link CaseBuilder}
         */
        CaseBuilder with(final Denomination denomination, int multiplier) {
            final int current = map.getOrDefault(Objects.requireNonNull(denomination),
                    Integer.valueOf(0)).intValue();
            if (current + multiplier > 0) {
                map.put(denomination, Integer.valueOf(current + multiplier));
            } else {
                map.remove(denomination);
            }
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * @return an unmodifiable copy of the underlying {@link Map}
         */
        Map<Denomination, Integer> getExpected() {
            return Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
        }

        /**
         * @return a human-reable output
         * @see Calculator#format(Map)
         */
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return Calculator.format(map);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### The internal representation of denominations

Just as I explained for [the question you linked](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/82689/coin-dispenser-program),
I don't see the reason to use `BigDecimal` to represent the denominations.
I think it would be better to make cents the base unit,
and use an `int` or `long` as the internal representation.

Here's `Denominator`, rewritten to use `int` as the internal representation.
I preserved the original API, so `Calculator` and `CalculatorTest` work with this unchanged (I cut out the JavaDoc for brevity). Notice the use of a `MULTIPLIER`, and its explanation in a comment.

```
enum Denomination {
    A_MILLION(1_000_000, "$1 million"),
    FIFTY_DOLLARS(50, "$50"),
    TWENTY_DOLLARS(20, "$20"),
    TEN_DOLLARS(10, "$10"),
    FIVE_DOLLARS(5, "$5"),
    DOLLAR_NINETY_NINE(1.99, "$1.99"),
    A_DOLLAR(1, "$1"),
    QUARTER(0.25, "25¢"),
    DIME(0.1, "10¢"),
    NICKEL(0.05, "5¢"),
    A_CENT(0.01, "1¢");

    private final int value;
    private String description;

    // Set to 10^k where k = maximum number of decimals to support in denominations
    // For example, to support 0.01 (1 cent), set to 10 ^ 2 = 100
    private static final int MULTIPLIER = 100;

    private Denomination(double value, final String description) {
        this.value = Double.valueOf(MULTIPLIER * value).intValue();
        this.description = Objects.requireNonNull(description);
    }

    public boolean canBreakdown(double input) {
        return MULTIPLIER * input >= value;
    }

    public double[] breakdown(double input) {
        int intValue = Double.valueOf(MULTIPLIER * input).intValue();
        int div = intValue / value;
        int remainder = intValue % value;
        return new double[] { div, (double) remainder / MULTIPLIER };
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return description;
    }

    public String toString(int multiplier) {
        return String.format("%d x %s", multiplier, toString());
    }

    public double multiply(int multiplier) {
        return (double) value * multiplier / MULTIPLIER;
    }    
}
```

#### 2-element `double[]` ?

It's always smelly when a method returns an array of `n` elements.
Since the size of the array is not part of the type,
the compiler cannot enforce that the array will really contain `n` elements.

This is especially awkward when the two values are not really the same type.
As is the case in `Denomination.breakdown`.
The method returns a 2-element `double[]`,
but the first element is actually supposed to be an `int`.
Putting the `int` in the `double[]` is easy enough,
but it puts a serious burden on callers,
who now have to convert the first element to `int` if they want to use it.

It would be better to create a custom class for the return value,
and properly enforce the types:

```
public static class Breakdown {
    final int count;
    final double remainder;

    public Breakdown(int count, double remainder) {
        this.count = count;
        this.remainder = remainder;
    }
}
```

Then the `breakdown` method becomes:

```
public Breakdown breakdown(double input) {
    int intValue = Double.valueOf(MULTIPLIER * input).intValue();
    int count = intValue / value;
    int remainder = intValue % value;
    return new Breakdown(count, (double) remainder / MULTIPLIER);
}
```

And the caller can be simpler as well:

```
public static Map<Denomination, Integer> getBreakdown(double input) {
    final Map<Denomination, Integer> result = new EnumMap<>(Denomination.class);
    double temp = input;
    for (final Denomination current : Denomination.values()) {
        if (current.canBreakdown(temp)) {
            Denomination.Breakdown breakdown = current.breakdown(temp);
            result.put(current, breakdown.count);
            temp = breakdown.remainder;
        }
    }
    return Collections.unmodifiableMap(result);
}
```

#### Naming

In the `getBreakdown` method mentioned in the earlier point,
look how much more readable it becomes if I rename `temp` to `remainder` and `current` to `denomination`:

```
public static Map<Denomination, Integer> getBreakdown(double input) {
    final Map<Denomination, Integer> result = new EnumMap<>(Denomination.class);
    double remainder = input;
    for (final Denomination denomination : Denomination.values()) {
        if (denomination.canBreakdown(remainder)) {
            Denomination.Breakdown breakdown = denomination.breakdown(remainder);
            result.put(denomination, breakdown.count);
            remainder = breakdown.remainder;
        }
    }
    return Collections.unmodifiableMap(result);
}
```

#### Weak "API" in `CaseBuilder`

The `CaseBuilder` class has some methods with some overlap in logic:

- `createEmpty`: create an empty, unmodifiable builder
- `create`: create a builder with some denomination
- `with`: add denominations

The overlap is in `create` and `with`.
The semantic rule is that you start with `create` and then add more denominations using `with`.
Another semantic rule is that `createEmpty` is actually unmodifiable:
you cannot start with `createEmpty` and add more items using `with` later.

It would be cleaner and more straightforward to have fewer methods with no overlap in logic, fewer semantic rules:

- `create`: create an empty builder. Or instead of this method, make use of a parameterless constructor
- `with`: add denominations

Something like this:

```
private static final class CaseBuilder {
    private final Map<Denomination, Integer> map = new EnumMap<>(Denomination.class);

    static CaseBuilder create() {
        return new CaseBuilder();
    }

    // ...
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
addCase(cases, 1.28, CaseBuilder.create()
        .with(Denomination.A_DOLLAR, 1)
        .with(Denomination.QUARTER, 1)
        .with(Denomination.A_CENT, 3));
```

#### Unnecessary boxing

The boxing is unnecessary in these statements:

> ```
> return String.format("%d x %s", Integer.valueOf(multiplier), toString());
>
> result.put(current, Integer.valueOf(Double.valueOf(parts[0]).intValue()));
> ```

You could write simpler as:

```
return String.format("%d x %s", multiplier, toString());

result.put(current, Double.valueOf(parts[0]).intValue());
```

The same goes for the test cases too.

#### Unnecessary unboxing

The unboxing is unnecessary in these statements:

> ```
> return Objects.requireNonNull(map).entrySet().stream()
>         .map(e -> e.getKey().toString(e.getValue().intValue()))
>         .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
>
> return Objects.requireNonNull(map).entrySet().stream()
>         .mapToDouble(e -> e.getKey().multiply(e.getValue().intValue())).sum();
> ```

You could write simpler as:

```
return Objects.requireNonNull(map).entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> e.getKey().toString(e.getValue()))
        .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));

return Objects.requireNonNull(map).entrySet().stream()
        .mapToDouble(e -> e.getKey().multiply(e.getValue())).sum();
```

The same goes for the test cases too.

Comment: Thanks for all the pointers, I only have one extra comment on `CaseBuilder`: the reason why I build it this way is because the expected `Map` must contain at least one pairing, as long as we are not breaking down 0. That is why there is the 'special case' `createEmpty()`. ;)