# Let's Break Down the Party by Breaking the Party Down Recursively

Tags: java, recursion

This is <s>a [rags-to-riches](/questions/tagged/rags-to-riches)</s> an overdue alternative implementation on my previous question: [Let's Break Down the Party](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/82760/lets-break-down-the-party)

This alternative uses the [`int` internal representation suggested by @janos](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/82768/27975) and recursion to arrive at the same results. For starters, here are the changes in `Denomination` `enum` to support the internal representation:

```
public enum Denomination {
    // values;

    static final int MULTIPLIER = 100;

    private final BigDecimal value;
    private final int centValue; // internal representation
    private String description;

    private Denomination(double value, final String description) {
        this.value = BigDecimal.valueOf(value);
        this.centValue = (int) (MULTIPLIER * value);
        this.description = Objects.requireNonNull(description);
    }

    /**
     * @return the value in cents
     */
    public int getCentValue() {
        return centValue;
    }

    ...

}
```

(I've kept the original `BigDecimal value` parts of code intact since I am  treating the new internal representation as an *addition* rather than a *replacement* to the original)

`MULTIPLIER_VALUE` uses the default (package) access modifier as it is only meant to be visible within the same package, i.e. the `Calculator`:

```
public class Calculator {

    /**
     * Break down the input into {@link Denomination} values by recursion.
     *
     * @param input the value to break down
     * @return an unmodifiable {@link Map} with the {@link Denomination} as keys and a
     *         positive integer, the multiplier, as values
     */
    public static Map<Denomination, Integer> getBreakdownRecursively(double input) {
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(
                recurse(Stream.of(Denomination.values()).iterator(), 
                        (int) (input * Denomination.MULTIPLIER), 
                        new EnumMap<>(Denomination.class)));
    }

    private static Map<Denomination, Integer> recurse(Iterator<Denomination> iterator,
            int input, Map<Denomination, Integer> result) {
        if (input == 0 || !iterator.hasNext()) {
            return result;
        }
        Denomination current = iterator.next();
        int nextInput = input;
        int units = input / current.getCentValue();
        if (units != 0) {
            result.put(current, Integer.valueOf(units));
            nextInput = input % current.getCentValue();
        }
        return recurse(iterator, nextInput, result);
    }

    ...

}
```

Rather than continuing encumbering my `Denomination` `enum` with the logic to do the 'break down', I have put the very simple calculations within the `recurse()` method. To showcase the results with the recursion method in the unit test, I have the following changes inside `CalculatorTest`:

```
public class CalculatorTest {

    @DataProvider(name = "test-cases")
    public Iterator<Object[]> getTestCases() {
        // return test cases as new Object[] { Double, CaseBuilder }
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "test-cases")
    public void test(final Double testValue, final CaseBuilder builder) {
        doTest(testValue, builder, Calculator::getBreakdown);
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "test-cases")
    public void testRecursion(final Double testValue, final CaseBuilder builder) {
        doTest(testValue, builder, Calculator::getBreakdownRecursively);
    }

    private void doTest(final Double testValue, final CaseBuilder builder,
            final DoubleFunction<Map<Denomination, Integer>> function) {
        Stream.of(testValue, builder).forEach(Objects::requireNonNull);
        final Map<Denomination, Integer> expected = builder.getExpected();
        assertThat(function.apply(testValue.doubleValue()), equalTo(expected));
        assertThat(Double.valueOf(Calculator.compute(expected)), equalTo(testValue));
    }

    ...

}
```

**Question**

Are there any other improvements for this implementation?

Comment: Your `BigDecimal` is imprecise since you're creating it from `double`, rather than from something exact (`String` or `int`). Isn't the value of your `NICKEL` something like `0.050000000000000003`?

Comment: @maaartinus to be frank that would be a nice comment on the linked question :) For the purposes of this question however, I deal with those minor inconsistencies by sweeping them under the metaphorical `MULTIPLIER` rug, as @janos did address this in the linked question. TL;DR: the `BigDecimal` usage is not part of this review.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I decided to introduce a `quantize()` method on `Denomination` to do the multiplication:

```
public static int quantize(double input) {
    return (int) (input * MULTIPLIER);
}
```

This changes the `Denomination`'s constructor:

```
this.centValue = quantize(value);
```

And the helper method itself:

```
public static Map<Denomination, Integer> getBreakdownRecursively(double input) {
    return recurse(Stream.of(Denomination.values()).iterator(),
            Denomination.quantize(input), new EnumMap<>(Denomination.class));
}
```

As hinted from above, I moved the `Collections.unmodifiableMap()` call to the last recursion within the `recurse()` method:

```
private static Map<Denomination, Integer> recurse(Iterator<Denomination> iterator,
        int input, Map<Denomination, Integer> result) {
    if (input == 0 || !iterator.hasNext()) {
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(result);
    }
    Denomination current = iterator.next();
    ...
}
```

Now, the original approach described in the question works well and looks simple enough, but what if I went a little deeper with Java 8 features? Looks like a nice place to introduce [`Map.computeIfAbsent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-)...

```
private static Map<Denomination, Integer> recurse(Iterator<Denomination> iterator,
        int input, Map<Denomination, Integer> result) {
    if (input == 0 || !iterator.hasNext()) {
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(result);
    }
    Denomination current = iterator.next();
    return recurse(iterator, result.computeIfAbsent(current, key ->
                Optional.of(Integer.valueOf(input / key.getCentValue()))
                    .filter(i -> i.intValue() != 0).orElse(null)) == null ? 
                        input : input % current.getCentValue(), result);
}
```

Sure, readability is sacrificed, but hey, just one `return` statement! By taking advantage of `computeIfAbsent()` and its return type, I can optionally store the output of the current iteration's breakdown (when the quotient is not zero), and determine what should be the next value to recuse with (the original `input`, or the modulus).

**edit**

I suppose I can improve the readability somewhat by this...

```
private static Integer getValue(int input) {
    // return Optional.of(Integer.valueOf(input))
    //                 .filter(i -> i.intValue() != 0).orElse(null);
    return input == 0 ? null : Integer.valueOf(input);
}
```

(fixed that)

The `return` statement will then read:

```
private static Map<Denomination, Integer> recurse(Iterator<Denomination> iterator,
        int input, Map<Denomination, Integer> result) {
    if (input == 0 || !iterator.hasNext()) {
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(result);
    }
    Denomination current = iterator.next();
    return recurse(iterator, result.computeIfAbsent(current, key ->
                getValue(input / key.getCentValue())) == null ? 
                        input : input % current.getCentValue(), result);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

A small remark.

You made the `MULTIPLIER` package `private` for a reason.
The problem is when other people will look at your code, they will think it's wrong, and that you forgot to put `private` there.

It is better to make `MULTIPLIER` as `private` and create a getter and setter for it.
With the getter/setter you could make the `package private`, and you can even add into the JavaDoc the reason for the `package private`.

Getters and setters are normally generated; so if there is no modifier before a getter/setter, then most people will understand that it is needed to be so.

Comment: Wells, we're roughly on the same page when I added my `quantize()` method... let's cut to the chase and award the bounty! :D

Comment: @h.j.k. thx for the bounty, even more that I'm surprised to receive it cause the answer was pretty short on a minor thing.

Comment: Wells I started the bounty to drive attention towards this... and it worked. :)